# Calculate elements in a array that are linear

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a large array of a tuple (data, time)
Part of the array contains data that has a linear slope.
Other data in the array is non-linear.
What algorithm can I use to determine 
Where does the linear slope start?
Where does the liner slope end?

Comment: All subsequences of length 2 are "linear". I suppose you want the largest "linear" subsequence?

Comment: You are going to have to define some kind of threshold for linearity.  You can fit a line to any data.

Comment: Agreed.  Assume that there is a threshold of say 100 points.

Comment: I was going to type an answer, but now I'm beginning to think you don't actually have linear data at all. Are the data linear, or when you say "linear" are you talking about some idealized hypothetical trend line for part of the data?

Comment: The data when plotted  falls into a linear trend line.  The delta between two points on the trend line may not be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Seems straightforward:

1. Sort tuples by time
2. Let `(d1, t1), (d2, t2), (d3, t3), (d4, t4), etc` be consecutive tuples
3. Calculate the gradient (slope) between each tuple: `(d2 - d1) / (t2 - t1), (d3 - d2) / (t3 - t2), etc.`
4. If the gradient is the same between multiple consecutive tuples (within a margin of error depending on your data), then those consecutive tuples must be on a linear line.

Answer (score 0):

Look up RANSAC algorithm for linear regression robust to outliers. Using a randomized approach, RANSAC will essentially find you an (approximately) largest set of points that are within a prescribed distance to a common line.